# How to prevent background colors from extending to gutter area in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a Mostly Fluid pattern in Bootstrap. In the row below the main row, the background colors are extending to fill the gutter area. How can i prevent this? Tried many things bit can't figure out a way.
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVncH.png)

```css
body {
  float: left;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.up {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  background-color: #64B5F6;
  width: 100%;
}

.down-l {
  font-size: 1em;
  background-color: #1976D2;
}

.down-r {
  font-size: 1em;
  background-color: #42A5F5;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Mostly Fluid by Bootstrap</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="MostlyFluid.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="up">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam sollicitudin, risus ac porta hendrerit, urna mauris malesuada dui, sed finibus justo justo vitae libero. Etiam placerat rutrum bibendum. Proin luctus sagittis lorem, in suscipit
            dui placerat ut. Maecenas finibus mollis metus, non tristique nibh pretium vitae. Praesent laoreet lacus in mollis viverra. Mauris nec metus a lorem venenatis malesuada in eu mi. Quisque vel eros augue. Praesent at nisl nec eros tempus pretium
            sit amet id justo. Nunc purus justo, dictum vel nisl a, convallis viverra enim. Pellentesque ac lectus vel orci gravida finibus. Suspendisse ac sollicitudin justo. Donec ut dui quam. Nullam vulputate, dui eget consectetur ultricies, justo
            nulla consectetur orci, nec vulputate mauris dui ut nunc. Phasellus molestie dui vitae ante sodales ultrices. Aenean non ullamcorper purus. Aliquam lacinia, justo at gravida tristique, sem sem rutrum ex, non fermentum erat neque sed ex. Fusce
            dolor libero, rutrum nec elit sit amet, eleifend mollis dui. Praesent at dignissim purus, id mattis elit. Duis et finibus nunc. Donec mi mi, posuere eu est at, gravida imperdiet ligula. Nam eleifend ut mauris id viverra. Ut sollicitudin tortor
            non justo dictum pharetra. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Morbi eu ornare nisi. Aenean accumsan egestas ultrices. Suspendisse finibus quam sed consequat hendrerit. Nunc non ultricies
            ligula. Aenean et arcu vel lectus lobortis varius. Vivamus pretium neque metus, sed rutrum ipsum iaculis in. Praesent molestie metus sed fermentum sollicitudin. Sed tempus massa ac malesuada cursus. Nunc dapibus orci id libero egestas vehicula.
            Maecenas semper bibendum facilisis. Ut a nulla consectetur, sagittis orci eget, sollicitudin neque. Maecenas tortor diam, porttitor ut urna egestas, tempor aliquet dolor. Nulla luctus aliquam dolor at imperdiet. Aliquam lobortis turpis fringilla
            sapien eleifend eleifend.</p>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 down-l">

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam sollicitudin, risus ac porta hendrerit, urna mauris malesuada dui, sed finibus justo justo vitae libero. Etiam placerat rutrum bibendum. Proin luctus sagittis lorem, in suscipit dui
          placerat ut. Maecenas finibus mollis metus, non tristique nibh pretium vitae. Praesent laoreet lacus in mollis viverra. Mauris nec metus a lorem venenatis malesuada in eu mi. Quisque vel eros augue. Praesent at nisl nec eros tempus pretium sit
          amet id justo. Nunc purus justo, dictum vel nisl a, convallis viverra enim. Pellentesque ac lectus vel orci gravida finibus. Suspendisse ac sollicitudin justo.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 down-r">

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam sollicitudin, risus ac porta hendrerit, urna mauris malesuada dui, sed finibus justo justo vitae libero. Etiam placerat rutrum bibendum. Proin luctus sagittis lorem, in suscipit dui
          placerat ut. Maecenas finibus mollis metus, non tristique nibh pretium vitae. Praesent laoreet lacus in mollis viverra. Mauris nec metus a lorem venenatis malesuada in eu mi. Quisque vel eros augue. Praesent at nisl nec eros tempus pretium sit
          amet id justo. Nunc purus justo, dictum vel nisl a, convallis viverra enim. Pellentesque ac lectus vel orci gravida finibus. Suspendisse ac sollicitudin justo.</p>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</body>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a class called .row--no-margin or any name. and make it

```
.row--no-margin{margin-left:0px; margin-right: 0px;}
```

now apply this class on your second row.

Here is the screenshoot: http://take.ms/QVoIa

Comment: Not working. When inspecting in chrome, row--no-margin class's attributes(margin-left and margin-right) appear to be striked out.

Comment: Solved. Putting the second row too into container-fluid does the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Apply this in the row where you don’t want to fill the gutter area

```
<div style="margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 0px;" class="row"> </div>
```